# C header <stdio.h>

Tags: c, header-files, stdio

I was trying to compile a 3-file C programme with 1 file cointaining tha main() , one containing headers related to a struct type I created and the third one the functions related to the struct. I was getting an error on the return temp; on a function in the third file, and I finally realized that I should remove the  header in that file in order the functions the work properly, but I have no idea why that worked!!

Could someone please explain me why?

Comment: Is there anything to do with `<stdio.h>`?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should post your code, at least the header. although we're collectively pretty good here, we're not great at mind reading :):):)

Answer (score 2):

Check:

1. You put header guards in your header files
2. You don't have function or object definitions in your headers but only declarations.

Comment: You have forgotten "the biggest of them all" :):):) Hint: there's a `struct` definition in the header; do you think the semicolon is there?